# .NET application keeps crashing on Windows (clr.dll)

Tags: .net, windows, exe

This is the Windows crash report that my .Net-based exe file generates. The problem is related to clr.dll

Would updating .Net help?

Should I use the Windows "hotfix"?

Help much appreciated.

```
Source
spit1.exe

Summary
Stopped working

Date
‎05/‎11/‎2016 14:34

Status
Not reported

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Investors\spit1.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   spit1.exe
Application Version:    4.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  51f67134
Fault Module Name:  clr.dll
Fault Module Version:   4.0.30319.34209
Fault Module Timestamp: 5348a1ef
Exception Code: c00000fd
Exception Offset:   0000000000009257
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
Locale ID:  2057
Additional Information 1:   67f4
Additional Information 2:   67f446138f435d3b51a74bd9fb86b17d
Additional Information 3:   e3b7
Additional Information 4:   e3b7b975b457d4dc9338dfb3498c6eae
```

Answer (score 0):

0xc00000fd means stack overflow (how apt). There is a bug in YOUR code, go find it.